# Trouble getting openSSL 1.0.2 working on CentOS 5.11

Tags: centos, curl, openssl

My office has some old REHL 5.11 servers on which I need to update the openSSL to take advantage of the latest TLS version. To figure it out, I created a CentOS 5.11 virtual server.

I found this guide: https://miteshshah.github.io/linux/centos/how-to-enable-openssl-1-0-2-a-tlsv1-1-and-tlsv1-2-on-centos-5-and-rhel5/

Unfortunately, after following all the steps, I get this error:

```
curl: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What is the output of `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: @r1verside `You have mail in /var/spool/mail/root`

Comment: That's nothing. That means that the output is nothing, and it should be `/usr/local/ssl/lib` at least

Comment: @r1verside Any advice on how to fix that? Should I just set the variable to that? In the base install of CentOS, curl worked fine, hitting using SSL3.

Comment: It should be set after using `ldconfig` according to the guide you followed but, as it isn't try setting it manually

Comment: Thanks. I actually went back an ran the `ldconfig` a second time, as I realized that was my mistake: I didn't output the file in the line above the ldconfig. Upon doing both those steps, looks like it works! Thanks!

Comment: Ok @RhoVisions let me add the answer so you can give me credit, if you don't mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is showing that the program is unable to locate the library `libssl.so.1.0.0`

For programs to be able to locate shared libraries, its location has to be listed in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environmental variable.

Include the path to `libssl.so.1.0.0` containing directory in the mentioned environmental variable and any software will be able to load it.